# Packet building with Scapy and Gevent

Tags: python, gevent, scapy

I'm trying to write a program, which works multithread using gevent.

The program will generate a packet, build it with scapy and then send it using raw_socket. Like so:

```
def worker(...):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW)
    s.bind((iface, socket.htons(0x0800)))
    packet = fragment(Ether()/IP(dst=dst, src=str(src))/TCP(dport=dport, sport=sport)/pay_load, fragsize=100)
    data = [piece.build() for piece in packet]
    for packet in data:
        s.send(packet)
```

The code run just fine in sequence, but when I spawn the thread using gevent, it'll fail at  `[piece.build() for piece in packet]` with `"WARNING: Child died unexpectedly. Packets may have not been sent 30405"`.

The best guess I can do is somehow `Packet.build` in Scapy does not work under threading. Can anybody help for a workaround or another way to generate packet?

Comment: I have never had any problems with gevent and Scapy together. Are you monkey-patching at the very top of your file?

Comment: sure I did, but the problem is with the building process of scapy, which it tried to send the packet (which I didn't want to send it yet), so the child failed and die

Comment: in that case it is possible there is some sort of bug within the `build` method. It may be worth inspecting the underlying source to see what the problem might be.

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: I have the same problem (but with eventlet).