# Scapy and Gevent?

Tags: python, gevent, scapy

I am thinking of using Scapy with some Gevent code and haven't really been able to find anything regarding reports of how the two libraries work together.

I was thinking of using two gevent subprocesses to pass traffic on two different interfaces.  Has anyone had experience working with these two libraries?

Answer (score 0):

A comment on this post [Packet building with Scapy and Gevent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17874278/packet-building-with-scapy-and-gevent) indicates that it may work:

> I have never had any problems with gevent and Scapy together. Are you monkey-patching at the very top of your file? –  Anorov Aug 10 '13 at 15:43